# javascript RegExp space character breaks test method

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to search using javascript, and I am using `RegExp` if I am just searching over one word it is fine, but if I search for 2 words e.g "a string" then I get no results - even though I am using a string that exists in the data that I am searching, here is my code,

```
GroupCollection.prototype.search = function(letters) {
  if(letters == "") return this;

  var pattern = new RegExp(letters, "gi");
  return _(this.filter(function(data) {
    return pattern.test(data.get("name"));
  }));
}
```

Is there any reason that my RegExp would not accept a space?

Comment: What do you set `letters` to?

Comment: In regex space is `\s`

Comment: @Prinzhorn letters are just a users input in a text field, they could effectively be any string.

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks but how would I form that so I can still use my modifiers?

Comment: But `new RegExp('a string').test('a string') === true`. You might also want to look into `String.indexOf` if you are matching strings to each other: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: @David you've lost me

Comment: @Udders can you set up an example where it fails? I’m not sure how you are using this function, what are the `letters` and `data.get('name')` ?

Comment: If `letters` comes from the user you should probably escape it.